# pattern not matching though declared

Tags: xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<root>
    <para>
      <label>5.</label> In essence, the Court in <star.page>19</star.page>
    </para>
    <para>
      <label><star.page>21</star.page> 13.</label>  Frankly, I cannot see how 
            one can escape          
    </para>
</root>
```

and using the below XSLT.

```
    <xsl:template match="para">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()[1][self::star.page]|./label/node()[1][self::star.page]" mode="first"/>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="star.page" mode="first">
  <xsl:if test="preceding::star.page">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
      <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <a name="{concat('pg_',.)}"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

here when i try to run this code, the first para `star.page` is getting caught, but the second `star.page`, i.e. `<para><label><star.page>21</star.page> 13.</label>...` is not getting caught. please let me know where am i going wrong. here i'm taking `[1]`, since i want to catch the first occurance.

Thanks

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples allowing us to easily reproduce the problem. In your XML sample you have white space between the para start tag and the label start tag, in your text with the inline code there is no white space.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, this is how it is in XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code on xmlplayground, both the star.page elements reach the template but the if  clause is preventing the first from reaching the output.